# Не могу установить tikz на Windows(TeXstudio)

Tags: latex

Обычно пакеты подгружались сами, но с tikz такого не происходит.

В `MiKTeX Console -> Packages` есть много пакетов связанных с `tikz`, но просто "tikz" нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете никаких рекомендаций не нашел. Везде написано, что пакет идет в комплекте с **MiKTeX.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пакета `tikz` нет, потому что он (пакет), вроде бы, называется `pgf` (вот он на [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)). Почему MikTeX недоустанавливает на лету некоторые из пакетов - не знаю. Но тикз тут не единственный пострадавший. Я бы рекомендовал снести эту версию-огрызок и поставить через сетевой инсталлер **полную** версию миктеха.

Comment: Скачивал установщик с сайта https://miktex.org/download. ( basic-miktex-2.9.6850-x64.exe )

Comment: @fimmind, я не говорю, что установщик неверный. Я говорю, что их "установка-по-запросу" показала себя как очень ненадежная. На моем опыте - не подгружаются векторные шрифты cm-super для кириллицы, из-за чего в pdf-документ попадали шрифты Type-3 (растровые, с корявой кодировкой, из-за чего нельзя из такого пдф-а нормально копипастить текст); Также, не доустанавливались некотрые пакеты из семейства ps-tricks. Были и другие косяки, не такие важные, поэтому я не запоминал. Лучший выход, вообще не использовать эту "установку-по-запросу".

Comment: @fimmind, И я имел ввиду вот этот установщик: https://miktex.org/download/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64/setup-2.9.6850-x64.exe   (`setup-2.9.6850-x64.exe`, не `basic-setup`)

Comment: Чем отличается `Download MiKTeX` от `Install MiKTeX`?

Comment: В установщике .

Comment: Он работает в 2 этапа - сначала надо `download`(скачать, да. зато потом можно много раз устанавливать с уже скачанного дистрибутива), а при втором запуске - `install`. Вся процедура может занять до 40 минут (если машина слабая и сеть не очень быстрая....)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Проблема решилась.